# How to plot table with two variables?

Tags: plotting, functions, list-manipulation

in my script,i have defined function current(cur), which is a function of two variables resistance(res) and time(tim).
Now what i need that for my function to pick a resistance value(which is a vector) and evaluate the function over a certain range of time and obtain the RMS value of current.
then i want to plot these values of current wrt their resistance values?

My program is as shown below:

```
Rlist = {10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9};
cur[tim_, res_] := sig*(r2^2 - r1^2)*num* omega*(1/2 - Exp[-(tim/(res*capa))]/(1 + Exp[Pi/(num*omega*res*capa)]))   

Pr[res_] := Evaluate@Table[cur[tim, res]^2*res, {tim, 0, (2*Pi)/(num*omega)}, {res, Rlist}];
ListLogLinearPlot[Pr[res],Frame -> True,PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01],Joined -> True,FrameLabel -> {Style["Load Resistance(\[CapitalOmega])", 16],Style["Average Power", 16]},FrameTicks -> {Rlist},PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.5]]
```

Although the above code is generating a graph, I am not sure whether the obtained graph is wrt resistance, as the axis ticks are integers like 1,2,3,4... and not resistance values as per the list.
(all others variables are constants defined earlier).

Kindly let me know whether the obtained graph is wrt resistance values or not?

Regards,
Sagar H P

[image: Power]

Comment: You did not specify constant values num, omega, capa.

Comment: sig*(r2^2 - r1^2)=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GerardF123 & @Alex Trounev, thank you for your time. 
I actually wanted to Plot the graph of RMS value of current in time domain wrt each resistance values and i implemented it as below.

```
data = Evaluate@ Table[{res, RootMeanSquare[Table[cur[tim, res]^2*res, {tim, 0, (2*Pi)/(num*omega)}]]}, {res,Rlist}]
```

I basically defined another table inside a table and constructed the graph.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Just a heads up... It is considered best practice to update your original post with your new findings/attempts instead of answering your own question.  The only time you would answer your own question is if you found the best solution yourself and you want document it.  Generally in those cases you would also let people know who gave you the suggestions in they are in other's answers.

Comment: Sure. Ill keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Put `sig*(r2^2 - r1^2)=1,num = 1; omega = 1; capa = 1;` then

```
Rlist = {10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9};
cur[tim_, res_] := 
 num*omega*(1/2 - 
    Exp[-(tim/(res*capa))]/(1 + Exp[Pi/(num*omega*res*capa)]))

Pr = Table[{res, cur[tim, res]^2*res}, {tim, 
    0, (2*Pi)/(num*omega)}, {res, Rlist}];
ListLogLinearPlot[Pr, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 Joined -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Load Resistance(\[CapitalOmega])", 16], 
   Style["Average Power", 16]}, FrameTicks -> {Rlist}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.5], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig1]